# Spring Cloud DataFlow - getting Execution ID after running task

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-cloud, airflow, spring-cloud-dataflow

Currently I'm moving from Spring XD as my workflow and runtime environment to Spring Cloud DataFlow and Apache Airflow. I want to create workflows in Airflow and use custom Airflow operator to run Spring Cloud Tasks on Spring Cloud DataFlow server by REST-API.

It's possible using:

```
curl -X GET http://SERVER:9393/tasks/deployments/...
```

Unfortunately DataFlow doesn't return job execution ID in this request to create simple way for monitoring of app. Is there a way to get this id in synchronic way? Because getting the last execution of specific job can lead to mistakes eg. missing job execution if I ran many the same jobs at the same time.

On Spring DataFlow I am running Spring Batch jobs so maybe better way is too somehow set execution job id and pass it as input parameter?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the following annotations to collect the task information from your bean:

```
public class MyBean {

    @BeforeTask
    public void methodA(TaskExecution taskExecution) {
    }

    @AfterTask
    public void methodB(TaskExecution taskExecution) {
    }

    @FailedTask
    public void methodC(TaskExecution taskExecution, Throwable throwable) {
    }
}
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-task/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#features-task-execution-listener